# Is there a way to to "hide" parameters of a command in Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

For my bot I want to implement random games (such as tossing a coin), and a betting system on top of that.
For exemple, anyone could use //coin_toss and the bot will answer "Heads" or "Tails", but if the command is //bet 15 coin_toss, the bot will also answer "Heads" or "Tails" but also say after "Congratulation you won X " or "You lost your bet".

```
    @commands.command()
    async def coin_toss(self, ctx: Context):
        outcomes = ("Heads", "Tails")
        result = outcomes[random.randint(0,1)]
        await ctx.reply(result)
        return result
```

The problem is that I want the //coin_toss command to have no parameters that can be passed via calling the command, but I still want parameters to be passed when calling it via self.coin_toss(ctx, amount_to_bet=5) for exemple. This also works for calling self.coin_toss

```
command: Command = utils.get(self.get_commands(), name=game_name)
result = await command(ctx, amount_to_bet)
```

For now I am using *args to "gather" all the arguments a user is trying to pass but I don't know if that can be bypassed when calling the command via a message in a channel.

```
    @commands.command(aliases=["pile_ou_face", "pof"])
    @has_user_role_from_config()
    async def coin_toss(self, ctx: Context, *args, amount_to_bet: float = 0):
        outcomes = ("Heads", "Tails")
        result = outcomes[random.randint(0,1)]
        await ctx.reply(result)
        return result
```

Is there a way to do that ? Feel free to comment if you want more precisions

Comment: "I want the //coin_toss command to have no parameters that can be passed via calling the command, but I still want parameters to be passed when calling it via self.coin_toss(ctx, amount_to_bet=5" When someone uses the bot command, what should the value of `amount_to_bet` be? Do you need to *detect* that the code was reached via the command?

Comment: If nothing is provided, the amount to bet should be 0, otherwise with using //bet the value could be any float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this answers your question about hiding parameters of a discord command, but I think it may give you some ideas on how you could implement your `bet` command in terms of your other game commands without needing to do so much argument parsing.

I have two suggestions. Think of coin_toss as a sub-routine of your bet function or implement a shared logical implementation of your coin_toss function.

## Coin Toss as a Sub-routine of Bet

```py
import os
import random

from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="//")


@bot.command()
async def coin_toss(ctx):
    outcomes = ("Heads", "Tails")
    result = outcomes[random.randint(0, 1)]
    await ctx.reply(result)
    return result


# Simulates your Utils Get Function
def get_commands():
    return [coin_toss]


def get_command_by_name(command_list, name):
    names = [c.name for c in command_list]
    if name not in names:
        return None
    else:
        return command_list[names.index(name)]


@bot.command()
async def bet(ctx, *args):
    if len(args) != 3:
        # Example //bet 15 Heads coin_toss
        await ctx.reply("Command is //bet amount outcome game_name")

    c = get_command_by_name(get_commands(), name=args[2])

    # Check Command Exists
    if c is None:
        await ctx.reply(f"Command {args[2]} does not exist")
    else:
        # Assumes result comes back as a string!!
        result = await c(ctx)
        # Compare case insensitive
        if result.lower() == args[1].lower():
            msg = f"Congratulation you won {args[0]}"
        else:
            msg = f'You lost your bet of {args[0]}'
        await ctx.reply(msg)


bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

I have a simulated your `get_commands`, and your `utils.get(self.get_commands(), name=value)` functions here so please update your `bet` implementation to reflect how your functions actually perform. I've also done this outside of a class for ease of testing, but please make the necessary changes to incorporate this code into your current implementation.

The downside of this approach is the delay. You're affectively sending two separate replies, once from the `coin_toss` function, then again from `bet` this can make for a delayed user experience.

## Coin Toss with Shared Logical Implementation

```py
import os
import random

from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="//")


# Separated Game Logic from the Bot Command
def coin_toss_logic():
    outcomes = ("Heads", "Tails")
    result = outcomes[random.randint(0, 1)]
    return result


@bot.command()
async def coin_toss(ctx):
    await ctx.reply(coin_toss_logic())


# Simulates your Utils Get Function
def get_commands():
    return [coin_toss_logic]


def get_command_by_name(command_list, name):
    # Strip off the "_logic" portion of your command names
    # uses __name__ since not a command anymore
    # Requires a consistent naming convention!
    names = [c.__name__[:-6] for c in command_list]
    if name not in names:
        return None
    else:
        return command_list[names.index(name)]


@bot.command()
async def bet(ctx, *args):
    if len(args) != 3:
        # Example //bet 15 Heads coin_toss
        await ctx.reply("Command is //bet amount outcome game_name")

    c = get_command_by_name(get_commands(), name=args[2])

    # Check Command Exists
    if c is None:
        await ctx.reply(f"Command {args[2]} does not exist")
    else:
        # Assumes result comes back as a string!!
        # No await needed since it's not an asyc command
        result = c()
        # Need to add Result to msg since not handled by command anymore
        msg = f'{result}\n'
        # Compare case insensitive
        if result.lower() == args[1].lower():
            msg += f"Congratulation you won {args[0]}"
        else:
            msg += f'You lost your bet of {args[0]}'
        await ctx.reply(msg)


bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

The benefit of this implementation being that there is less delay between messages, however, there is more work because you have essentially two separate functions that both map to the same name.

Comment: Thank you for your long answer.
The problem with that approach is that you'd have to do more work for each new game added (adding the command in the list of get_commands)
Also, there already exists function to get the commands of a cog etc.

The best way to implement what I want is might parameters that cannot be passed by users, but that can be passed when explicitly calling the function from the code

I'll still accept your answer because this is probably the closest i'll get, but I'll update my question if I find something that works

Comment: Like I said in my answer, the get_commands was just to simulate the utils get commands that you referenced. In SO answers it is often best to write the minimal amount of code, which is why I didn't go through and implement the setup as thoroughly as I might if I wanted to put this into production. Best of luck on your search for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled across the same problem recently (if I understood you correctly):
To solve this you can use an attribute ["extras"](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=extra#discord.Interaction.extras) in discord.py

and then get it using something like this code:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="test", description="testing extras params", extras=<your-dictionary>)
...
[ctx | interaction] .command.extras.get(<your-parameter>)
```

Hope, it will help.